# What are the differences (if any) in brain activity when hallucinating versus perceiving a real object?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, perception

I was wondering if there is difference in brain activity when someone is hallucinating an object, say a giraffe compared to when someone is genuinely observing a real giraffe?